# My thrown exceptions in Java aren't working

Tags: java, exception

I'm working on a project where we are to create a cash register system that gives errors for orders of $0.00 and 0 total items. The code for the exceptions is below. I have to use this method.

```
  public boolean ValidateOrderTotal(double total)  
  {
      boolean validTotalFlag = true;
      try
      {
          if (total < 0)
          Exception invalidTotalEX = new Exception ("Total mst be >= $0.00");
          throw invalidTotalEX;
      }
  catch (Exception invalidTotalEX)(
  validTotalFlag = false;
  SetTotal(0.00);
  System.out.println(invalidTotalEX);
  }

return validTotalFlag;

public boolean ValidateOrderProductTotal (double totalItems)
{
boolean validProdctTotalFlag = true;
try
{
if (totalItems < 0)
(Exception invalidProductTotalEX = new Exception ("Product total must be >=0");
throw invalidProductTotalEX;
}
}
catch (Exception invalidProductTotalEX)(
validProdctTotalFlag = false);
SettotalItems (0);
system.out.println (invalidProductTotalEX);
)
return valid ProductTotalFlag
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I see you conform to the obfuscation school of formatting. Any chance you could format your code legibly for us mere mortals?

Comment: I don't see how this code would even compile.

Comment: Also, please don't use exceptions for control flow. You can dramatically simplify your code by simply throwing _out_ an exception (instead of returning a return value) if the input is invalid.

Comment: Your if is broken, you can write it shorter as `if (total < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("total must be > 0 but was " + total);`

Comment: Your code won't compile, the syntax of your code is incorrect. Close the methods after return statements. Put braces for if statements. Catch block starts with a curly brace.

Answer (score 2):

```
      if (total < 0)
      Exception invalidTotalEX = new Exception ("Total mst be >= $0.00");
      throw invalidTotalEX;
```

needs curly braces

```
      if (total < 0) {
          Exception invalidTotalEX = new Exception ("Total mst be >= $0.00");
          throw invalidTotalEX;
      }
```

You have a second if with the exact same issue.

Also your catch blocks need to use `{` and `}` around the statements. You are using `(` and `)` in some places.

Answer (score 1):

As it throws error when it is 0 it should be:

```
if (total <= 0) {
          Exception invalidTotalEX = new Exception ("Total mst be > $0.00");
          throw invalidTotalEX;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

"catch (Exception invalidTotalEX)(" - 
there should be last '{' after "catch (Exception invalidTotalEX)(" instead of '('

Variable name does not matter, for example:

```
viktor@Viks-pro:~/tmp/test $ cat ExTest.java
import java.util.*;
public class ExTest
{   public static void main(String[] args)
    {   try
        {   throw new Exception("Something should be different");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {   System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}viktor@Viks-pro:~/tmp/test $ java ExTest
Exception: Something should be different
```